# React: Checkbox and file on controlled forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For inputs with type text it's easy, with onChange() I update the state calling setState() and showing the state on the input through its value attribute. However, for checkboxes and even more for file, I'm totally lost.

Which would be the:

1. handler
2. property of the event object
3. attribute
   ... for input>checkbox and input>file

Example of input>text

1. onChange()
2. event.target.value
3. value

Answer (score 1):

For checkbox you can check using using the following :

```
handleChange(e) {
  console.log(e.target.checked);
}
<input 
  type="checkbox" 
  name="checkbox"
  onChange={ this.handleChange } 
/>
```

For files you can go as follows:

```
handleUploadFile(e) {
  let selectedFile = e.target.files;
  //if single file
  console.log(selectedFile[0]);
  //else loop around the files
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @yash-thakur So, we don´t set the state and assign a value for x-attribute of that element...? Example: <input type="checkbox"  checked={this.state.checkedState} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e.target.checked)} /> Thanks again!

Comment: You can setState int the handleChange function and used that state as per what you mentioned in your above comment.